# How to Databind Xaml Path elements

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have an ItemsControl bound to a collection of objects, each of which contain a property of the type Windows.UI.Xaml.Shape.Path

I have the following Xaml as an ItemTemplate:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Path Data="{Binding MyPathProperty}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

This fails because the Path.Data property is expecting an object of type Geometry.

What is the correct way to bind the entire Path object to the item itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ContentPresenter --

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyPathProperty}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Perfect, so simple. Cheers.